# asp.net mvc Binder not update the RoleId value in Edit view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an extended User class like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
  public string Nombre { get; set; }
  public string Apellidos { get; set; }
  public int DepartamentoID { get; set; }
  public Departamento Departamento { get; set; }
}
```

In my Edit view I have this field definition:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
   <div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Roles.ElementAtOrDefault(0).RoleId, (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleList, "Seleccionar un rol", new { @class = "form-control" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Roles.FirstOrDefault().RoleId)
   </div>
</div>
```

When I send the form, the Roles collection is empty.

Why the Binder does not add the role to the Roles collection?

Greetings and thanks.

I try to add more information to respond to Rajesh's comments.

In the Get action the model contains the information of the role, and the view shows it correctly. A drop-down list shows the available roles, and the user's role appears selected. When in the view I select another different role and send the form, in the Post action, the Roles collection of the model no longer contains information.

[GET action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qv4C.jpg)

[POST action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFUMr.jpg)

I do not know how to debug the work of the Binder

Comment: Debug and check why the Roles is empty, Are you getting the model in Get request? if then please check it properly whether its binding. More over we can see the User Model only here in the code which you added here where are the other codes like Roles and all, Please add them so that it will be easy to check.

Comment: Can you not use separate ViewModel instead of POCO Entity class?

Comment: Win, of course. I can use a ViewModel.
But my question is, why the Binder does not fill the information automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the Binder does not add the role to the Roles collection?

It happens because `@Html.DropDownListFor` and default model binder are not smart enough. Your `@Html.DropDownListFor` produces something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="RoleId" name="RoleId">
    <option value="1">Role_1</option>
    <option value="2">Role_2</option>
</select>
```

Since `name=RoleId` the model binder will try to bind it to `RoleId` property of your model and it knows nothing about `Roles` property and moreover that `Roles` prop is enumerable.

To make it work your model must have `RoleId` property or you can use `Html.ListBoxFor` extension if you want to select multiple roles:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedRoles, (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Then your model must have `public List<string> SelectedRoles { get; set; }` property.

Another option is to create a custom model binder using [`IModelBinder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd505004(v=vs.118)) interface. This option gives you unlimited capabilities to map the request data to the model.